# Fetch required column from a file with \001 delimiter

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am storing output of pig file in a directory
Which contains lines with multiple columns separated by  delimiter `\\u0001`.

Now in shell script I want to fetch 7th column field from the output.

I tried below commands however didn’t get required output:

```
cnt=`awk -F '^A' '{print $7,$1}' $f`
cnt=`cut -d'\\u0001' -f8 $f | awk '{s+=$0}END{print s+0}'`
```

How to achieve the same?

---

Here is sample file:

```
printf "c1\\u0001c2\\u0001c3\\u0001c4\\u0001c5\\u0001c6\\u0001c7\\u0001c8" > 001.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following syntax:

```
awk -F '\001' '{print $7}' < myfile
```

where:

- `-F` - use the next arg as field separator,
- `'\001'` - method of expressing a byte with a value of 1,
- `'{print $7}'` - for every line of input, output the 7th field followed by a newline,
- `< myfile` - use `myfile` as input.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain what this code does and how it addresses the problem?  Unexplained code is [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because it doesn't teach the solution (and RTFM isn't a substitute).  Your answers will attract more upvotes with some explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: This answer should have been explained.

Comment: awk - the program

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` command for that, e.g.

```
cut -d $'\001' -f7 001.txt
```

Where `-d` is your delimiter and `-f` is your column number.